# KnexPg 'update()' not updating

Tags: sql, sails.js, knex.js

In my SailsJS app, I have the following code:

```
var idValue = this.id;
var quantitiesLockedValue = this.quantitiesLocked;

const query = knexPg.select().from('MealTemplate as m');
query.where('m.id', idValue).update({ quantitiesLocked: 
  quantitiesLockedValue });
```

The update call is simply not working.  I know from console logs that the quantiesLockedValue is 'false' but when I check in the db it is still TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

The idValue I was passing in was null.  That was the problem.